# How do you google search for a question about stacks or stack overflow on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google

I prefer using google to search questions on Stack Overflow because they have a very good searching algorithm/AI. However, it's impossible to search for questions about stack overflow on Stack Overflow, because if you search for stack overflow it will interpret it as the website Stack Overflow rather than the subject of a stack overflow.

Example: Searching Android Activity Stack will actually result in results from stackoverflow.com containing the words "Android" and "activity" but not necessarily the word "stack".

How do I search for something about a stack overflow, or even simply the word "stack", on Stack Overflow if using google?

Comment: Search for `site:stackoverflow.com android "Activity Stack"` if you must. Searching for stack overflow errors is more tricky but I think there are only so many things to know about stacks or stack overflows and there are better resources than SO to learn about them. Just use the site's search and stackoverflow tag.

Comment: Have you tried [symbol hound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=Stack+Android)

Comment: I had to read the title 3 times before I understood it.

Comment: Actually this is off-topic for this site.... because it's about Google. ([right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

Answer (score 4):

One way you can get better results is to put quotes around your search terms.

**"the Android Activity Stack"**

Another way is to use the ampersand

**Android & Activity & Stack**

Or you can use both

**Android & "Activity Stack"**