# How to search for a problem containing "overflow" in google without getting false hits?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search

When I search for a solution involving the word "overflow" (like " ... buffer overflow ...") in google I get many false positives (since most pages here contain "Stack overflow" ;-)).

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I fear this is googles problem, but I believe you can set up exclusions in your searches

Comment: Also I think you need a better example a [google search for buffer overflow](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=butter+ovrflow&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=oVwwUuO4EomQ7AaCjoGoAg#q=buffer+overflow&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&start=10) doesn't have any stack overflow stuff on the first page

Comment: Related [How do you google search for a question about stacks or stack overflow on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195970/how-do-you-google-search-for-a-question-about-stacks-or-stack-overflow-on-stack)

Comment: I propose renaming the whole site to "BlipBlorpFloop" for SEO purposes.

Comment: @Wooble: Maybe I should switch from "discussion" to "feature-request" ;-)?

Answer (score 6):

`site:stackoverflow.com "stack overflow"` illustrates that it's difficult to exclude titles when doing a Google search, which is where you're getting the results that you see.

It's better to do a specific search using our (now very much improved) search functionality. To find all questions tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c) with 'stack overflow' somewhere in the body:

```
[c] is:question body:"stack overflow"
```

... is the query to use. Adjust to fit, but I really recommend just searching on SO if you've got something like 'overflow' in your query.